# How do I use loop to extract specific headers in dataframe? (using R Studio)

Tags: r

So the data goes like this.

1. SalesData is a data.frame.
2. SalesData$Day1 is numeric column including sales data of each member on first day. Same goes for $Day2, $Day3 ... $Day50

I'm trying to make a new column with 50 numeric data, sum of each day's sale, by using loop.

I tried

```
for (i in 1:50)
{SalesData$Dailysum[i] <- sum(SalesData$get(colnames(SalesData)[i]))

Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

apparently I can't use get(colnames(SalesData)[i] to extract specific header.

```
SalesData$colnames(SalesData)[i]
```

didn't work either.

Is there any way to use loop to extract header, and use it for loop?

Comment: Do you just want `colSums(SalesData)`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar I tried it, but unfortunately it is not applicable since SalesData$names is a character column including sales team's name. It works perfectly after I tried deleting $names column, though. Thank you for help.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a minimal example reproducing the format of your data ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just do instead of `get` as it works with either numeric index or column names

```
for(i in 1:50)
  SalesData$Dailysum[i] <- sum(SalesData[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we could also do with `summarise` while checking if the column type is `numeric` or not

```
library(dplyr)
SalesData %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Wow! it works! Thank you! May I ask my code didn't work?

Comment: @EliyahJung your code didn't work because you are using `get` on the column names with `$`.  1) `get` is not needed, 2) use `[[` for subsetting from an object name because `$` look for literal evaluation i.e. ` SalesData[[names(SalesData)[1]]]` work. Regarding, `get`, it looks for the object in the global env, while the column name is only available in the env of the dataset SalesData